# Как не грузить все сразу используя systemjs в качестве загрузчика скриптов?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Допустим на сайте есть множество разделов, за каждый из них отвечает какой-то класс-обработчик конкретной страницы.

Когда мы заходим на любую страницу, срабатывает основной файл который инициализирует роутер `let router = new Router();` который определяет на какой странице, какой класс-обработчик нужно инициализировать (т.е. создать его инстанс и может выполнить какой-то метод). Примерно так это выглядит:

```
import {HomePageController} from "../modules/homePageController";
import {page1Controller} from "../modules/page1Controller";
import {page2Controller} from "../modules/page2Controller";
import {page3Controller} from "../modules/page3Controller";
import {page4Controller} from "../modules/page4Controller";

export class RouterMap{

    constructor(){
        return this;
    }

    protected routes = {
        "/:hl/$": {
            controller: HomePageController,
            handlerMethod: "onInit",
            onLeaveHandlerMethod: "onLeave"
        },
        "/:hl/p1": {
            controller: page1Controller,
            handlerMethod: "onInit",
            onLeaveHandlerMethod: "onLeave"
        },
        "/:hl/p2": {
            controller: page2Controller,
            handlerMethod: "onInit",
            onLeaveHandlerMethod: "onLeave"
        },
        "/:hl/p3": {
            controller: page3Controller,
            handlerMethod: "onInit"
        },
        "/:hl/p4": {
            controller: page4Controller,
            handlerMethod: "onInit",
            route:{
                "/:id": {
                    handlerMethod: "onInit"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Суть проблемы в том что при загрузке любой страницы, systemjs подгрузит все что мы импортнули в `RouterMap` что представлен выше, и все что импортнуто в каждый класс-обработчик что в `RouterMap` есть (HomePageController, page1Controller, page2Controller, page3Controller, page4Controller) и так же что импортнуто в каждый из них. И это очень плохо, что если проект большой и общий импорт составит около к примеру 400 файлов (systemjs их всегда будет грузить все сразу), а на конкретно одной странице используется в импорте не более 10 файлов? как заставить systemjs работать иначе, и не грузить то что не будем использовать? я так подозреваю что нужно переписать роутер, но пока не пойму как, **ведь мы же не можем динамически (неявно) импортировать классы, а только явно?** или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Какой библиотекой для маршрутизации запросов пользуетесь?

Comment: @PavelMayorov самодельная, она анализирует url, сравнивает в том что в RouterMap и выполняет нужный метод нужного класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно при написании SPA (Single-Page Application) предполагается, что пользователь со страницы уходить не будет - а потому в загрузке сразу всех файлов нет ничего страшного. Если нужно ее ускорить - можно собрать бандлы (bundle).

Если же у вас многостраничный сайт - вам не нужны роуты.

---

Если же у вас какой-то специфический случай - то можно встроить загрузку модулей в механизм маршрутизации.

Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
    protected routes = {
        "/:hl/$": {
            controllerModule: "modules/homePageController",
            controllerName: "HomePageController",
            handlerMethod: "onInit",
            onLeaveHandlerMethod: "onLeave"
        },
    };
```

Получение контроллера из маршрута:

```
System.import(r.controllerModule).then(module => {
  var controller = module[r.controllerName];
  // делаем что-то с контроллером
})
```

Comment: при каждом заходе по роуту будет производится новая загрузка? или информация где-то кешируется?

Comment: @Grundy конечно же кешируется. Модуль - всегда синглтон, это основы модулей. Что в js, что в Python, что в C# (в последнем роль модулей играют классы).

Comment: Ну, мало ли, это же зависит от реализации того же systemjs

Comment: @Grundy systemjs - это просто полифил

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, переписал свой роутер, все работает и кэшируется. Спасибо!

Comment: А мне не понятно о чем вообще разговор.. System нужен только для удобной разработки и использовать его в продакшен вообще бессмысленно, так как в реальных приложениях борьба идет за каждую секунду, а System затормозит все на десятки...

Comment: @OlmerDale в SPA - так и есть. Но веб не ограничивается SPA.

Comment: @OlmerDale кроме того, не забывайте про бандлинг. Он куда важнее для ускорения работы, нежели прелоад.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а что можно ещё делать где будет разница от загрузки всех модулей сразу?

Comment: @OlmerDale не понял вашего последнего комментария

Comment: @PavelMayorov, бандлы я даже в расчет не беру, это само собой разумеется.

Comment: @OlmerDale ну так если бандлы - "это само собой разумеется", то откуда возьмется лаг в десятки секунд?

Comment: @PavelMayorov по поводу последнего.. Вы говорите что в spa так оно и есть, типа не нужно использовать system. А ещё говорите что есть ещё что-то кроме вэба. Так вот я спрашиваю - а какой вид существует ещё и почему для него не важна скорость запуска, но важен размер загружаемых файлов?

Comment: @OlmerDale не кроме вэба, а в вебе. Кроме SPA есть еще, внезапно, сайты с контентом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, про бандлы + system я не подумал, Вы правы.